# Change the color of an ImageView with on button click?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to change the color of an imageView when a button is clicked, I've tried this so far.

```
ImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(102,31,31));
```

is there anything else i can use besides

```
ImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
```

Please help.

Comment: I would like to add that I am new to android/java programming

Comment: Dont name your variable `ImageView`, it is a class name. if anything name it `imageView`

Comment: You are working on ImageView class. You should use this method on ImageView Object. I wonder how did you managed to call setBackgroundColor on ImageView class since it is not static ?

Comment: It is named imgOne, but I left it like that for convenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a color variable, like so :

```
int yellow = Color.ParseColor("#XXXXXX");

...

imageView.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
ImageView  backgroundImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50));
```

Or else change the background color of parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
ImageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourColor))
```

In your `color.xml` add yourColor :

```
<color name="yourColor">#yourColorCode</color>
```